# How to set VNC security settings using SSH? `No security types supported. Server sent security types, but we do not support any of them`

Tags: raspbian, ssh, vnc

With the latest Dist-upgrade, it appears the VNC security settings have been changed which means I cannot access my Pi through VNC until they are changed back. I have SSH access.

As the Pi is over 100 miles away I would like to find a way of changing the security settings to enable me to connect with VNC again without having to be present. I remotely connect to a PC on the remote network and I have SSH access to the PI through that PC.

The error I get when trying to connect is "Error in TightVNC Viewer. No security types supported. Server sent security types, but we do not support any of them"

To make the answers to the question as useful as possible to anyone with a similar problem in the future I will phrase it as follows.

Using only SSH how can I ensure I have suitable VNC security settings?

Answer (score 31):

To be able to use a non-compatible realvnc client you have to [downgrade](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) the security of the realvnc server to use vnc password authentication. 
To be able to to this without a desktop connection open a SSH session:

1. Edit the config file in /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
2. Add the following lines at the end of the file

   ```
   Authentication=VncAuth
   Encryption=AlwaysOff
   Password=e0fd0472492935da
   ```
3. Restart the server

This will set the authentication with the password: ***foobar***. In order to change the password,

```
vncpasswd -service
```

Connection tested with TigerVNC 1.7.1

Comment: This saved me when using `vncserver -flag` didn't work from my terminal. Tested with TightVNC 2.8.27. Thanks!

Comment: I confirm this solution still works as of today using the latest RPiOS release named "bullseye"

Comment: Dead solution unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [realvnc viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/). There is some difference in the security settings between the two which produces that message.

Comment: I wanted to post - Thank you that worked although for other people with the same issue they may need to know that you will need to sign in with your username and password which you use to sign into your Pi not the password used to sign into tightVNC. I have upvoted but it will not show until I get 15 rep.

Comment: If anyone has the answer to the original question I would still like to know a way of restoring the security types (using SSH) to enable me to use the TightVNC viewer I have been using previously.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps can be executed from an SSH session:

**1. Edit the RealVNC server configuration file:**

*sudo vi /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11*

**2. Insert, edit, or replace the following lines:**

*Authentication=VncAuth*

*Encryption=AlwaysOff*

**3. Choose a VNC server authentication password (does not require sudo):**

*vncpasswd -print*

**4. Copy the ENTIRE "Password=...encrypted password..." line and PASTE or REPLACE it into the file:**

*/root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11*

**5. RESTART the RealVNC server:**

*sudo systemctl restart vncserver-x11-serviced*

You should now be able to establish a VNC session using TightVNC or any other viewer.  Use the password chosen in step 3.

I know this solution is 2 years late, but I'm pissed that nobody else figured it out, because it only took me 4 hours.

Comment: for the default VNC server in PI (RealVNC)... to not fiddle with root (as always recomended)... and follow the best-practices... change the /etc/vnc/config.d/common.custom file with the authentication options--- I'll post the instructions as an aswer...

Comment: Still seems to not want to connect for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to enable TightVNC viewer with this issue is to install and open VNC viewer in Chrome. From there you can access the Pi and its VNC server settings. Go to options, set authentication to "VNC password" and Encryption to "Prefer Off". See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176408

After that I was again able to use TightVNC.

Answer (score 0):

***Disable encryption to use TightVNC or other VNC client***

- *to not fiddle with root (as always recomended)*
- *and follow the Ux* best-practices*
- *for RealVNC Server change the `/etc/vnc/config.d/common.custom` file with the authentication options*

Process:

- digest a VNC password for the config file and grab the output

  ```
  vncpasswd -print <password>
  ```
- edit the default VNC daemon common.custom configuration

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/vnc/config.d/common.custom
  ```
- add the options and the digest obtained with vncpasswd -print to common.custom file

  ```
  Authentication=VncAuth
  Encryption=AlwaysOff
  Password=...
  ```
- save and restart RealVNC server (or reboot, sometimes its better...)

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart vncserver-x11-serviced
  ```

Note:

- as an SysOp/Dev advise...
- if possible use XRDP...
- it's faster and more secure...
- though there are many situations we must use VNC...